# Excel VBA to send data to webpage that runs javascript - HOW?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I have a webpage that we have as a tool, where we(user) have to input few data, then we click submit and we obtain some calculated result in next page and this webpage is used internal to our company only.
By viewing the "view source" on the page it says me that the page runs on javasript and with "post" and "action" method:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="FF%20MoWIP%20-%20Create%20Order%20Updated_CA_WAN_files/r3.js"></script>

<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="CreateOrder.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
```

Among the 15 fields that are present on that page, only 2 fields vary always....and there is 1 field which is a drop-down list.....and any change on the value chosen on that field alters the contents of other field which is again another drop-down list based on the previous value selected.

And so now, what i am trying to achieve is to write a VBA code in Excel to send the values to those fields in that web page and expect the result (and notify if error), then capture the result into a different/same worksheet.

Please, could someone advice me what could be the best method to start working on this.
Any insight/help will be much appreciable.

I have knowledge level on somewhat been beginner to intermediate in excel vba.

Thank you,

Regards,
Shashi

Answer (score 0):

Check the below URL which shows way to scrap data from webpage to excel using VBA. Hope this will help you:

> http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm

Comment: Hi Paresh, its not just that, what i need is to "send data to a webpage from excel. Please help again. Thanks.